# How to stabilize a matrix with a high condition number?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, condition-number

If my 2-norm condition number is large then my matrix is ill-conditioned. I'm able to determine if my matrix is ill-conditioned using the condition number, however once I know that this is the case, how can I combat it?

Are there any methods I can use to stabilize the matrix so that it is no longer ill-conditioned?

Comment: Regularization (e.g. Tikhonov regularization)?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem in my own research. Some people have luck using a preconditioning matrix, though I have not had success with this approach. Typically, SVD is known for being one of the most accurate approaches for nearly any problem, but it is much slower than other approaches, and it still suffers from common problems like finite-precision arithmetic and high condition numbers.